# React Hook clean/show Errors message while typing

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-hook-form

I just start using React and I'm working with `react-hook-form` to manage warning/error messages.

I built the form below:

```
const { register, handleSubmit, errors } = useForm();

<form
    id="contactForm"
    onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}
>
    <div className="messages"></div>
    <div className="row">
        <div className="col-md-6">
            <div className="form-group">
                <label htmlFor="firstName">
                    First Name
                </label>
                {errors.firstName && (
                    <span className="help-block with-errors">
                        Firstname is required. Minimum of 2 letters.
                    </span>
                <input
                    id="form_name"
                    type="text"
                    name="firstName"
                    className="form-control"
                    placeholder="Type First name"
                    ref={register({
                        required: "Required",
                        minLength: 2
                    })}
                />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div className="col-md-6">
            <div className="form-group">
                <label htmlFor="lastName">
                    Last Name
                </label>
                {errors.lastName && (
                    <span className="help-block with-errors">
                        Lastname is required.
                    </span>
                )}
                <input
                    id="form_lastname"
                    type="text"
                    name="lastName"
                    className="form-control"
                    placeholder="Type Last name"
                    ref={register({
                        required: "Required",
                    })}
                />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

It works perfect when I submit the form. However, how can I make the error message shows while typing? For example, in the first name, it should show if I just type one character and disappear if I have 2 or more.

Also, do I need to clean the errors variable after submitting the form? If so, how should I clean it?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as the [api](https://react-hook-form.com/api) displays, `useForm()` can take an object with some arguments. if you pass `mode` you can select when validation occurs. to validate on every change pass `onChange` string option:

```
const { register, handleSubmit, errors } = useForm({ mode: 'onChange' });
```

Comment: Thank you! It was what I was looking for